# How to populate the data from different schema and different table to other schema to other table

Tags: sql

-->There are three table A,B and C. Table A and B belongs to Same Schema where C belongs to other. 
--> my condition is
   tableA(column1,column2,column3),tableB(column4,column2,column3),.tableC(column1,column5,column6)

I want to insert value in table A by populating the value of table B and C and the condition is column1 value is equal to 3

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using, but nothing else.

Comment: what is the relation between table B and Table C ??

Comment: Check if you have any DB links.

Comment: There is no relation between Table B and Table C Table A related to table B and C via Column

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two-part naming to move data around between schemas.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT B.Col4, C.Col5, B.Col6
FROM Schema_A.Table_B AS B
INNER JOIN Schema_B.Table_C AS C
    ON B.ID = C.ID
;
```

Of course you can add a `WHERE` clause to this to make it more specific, or whatever else you need to do; but the four/three/two-part naming convention remains the same.

You can even do a `JOIN` between databases with three-part naming:

```
FROM DB1.Schema_A.Table_A AS A
INNER JOIN DB2.Schema_X.Table_X AS X
    ON A.ID = X.ID
;
```